# Make multiline (align within aligned) look better?

Tags: equations, align, amsmath

I have a very long set of equations that I want to give in my thesis and I'm having a hard time formatting it to something that looks "nice".
I have been going over a lot of suggestions on this site, and it has already led me to the following:

```
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:ML:LSTM:backpropagation_example}
\begin{aligned}
    \frac{\partial \boldsymbol{h}_{i,j}}{\partial \boldsymbol{W}^{(s)}} & = \frac{\partial \boldsymbol{o}_{i,j}}{\partial \boldsymbol{W}^{(s)}} \odot g(\boldsymbol{c}_{i,j}) +\boldsymbol{o}_{i,j} \odot \frac{\partial g(\boldsymbol{c}_{i,j})}{\partial \boldsymbol{W}^{(s)}}, \\[0.3em]
    & \begin{aligned}
        = & \left( \boldsymbol{o}_{i,j} (1 - \boldsymbol{o}_{i,j}) \boldsymbol{R}^{(0)}\frac{\partial \boldsymbol{h}_{i,j-1}}{\partial \boldsymbol{W}^{(s)}} \right) \odot g(\boldsymbol{c}_{i,j}) \\ & + \boldsymbol{o}_{i,j} \odot \left( \left(1 - \tanh^2{(\boldsymbol{c}_{i,j})} \right) \frac{\partial \boldsymbol{c}_{i,j}}{\partial \boldsymbol{W}^{(s)}} \right), \end{aligned} \\[0.3em]
    & \begin{aligned}
        = &\left( \boldsymbol{o}_{i,j} (1 - \boldsymbol{o}_{i,j}) \boldsymbol{R}^{(0)}\frac{\partial \boldsymbol{h}_{i,j-1}}{\partial \boldsymbol{W}^{(s)}} \right) \odot g(\boldsymbol{c}_{i,j}) \\ & + \boldsymbol{o}_{i,j} \odot \left( \left(1 - \tanh^2{(\boldsymbol{c}_{i,j})} \right) \left( \frac{\partial \boldsymbol{s}_{i,j}}{\partial \boldsymbol{W}^{(s)}} \odot \boldsymbol{z}_{i,j} + \boldsymbol{f}_{i,j} \odot \frac{\partial \boldsymbol{c}_{i,j-1}}{\partial \boldsymbol{W}^{(s)}} \right) \right), 
    \end{aligned}\\[0.3em]
    & \begin{aligned}
        = &\left( \boldsymbol{o}_{i,j} (1 - \boldsymbol{o}_{i,j}) \boldsymbol{R}^{(0)}\frac{\partial \boldsymbol{h}_{i,j-1}}{\partial \boldsymbol{W}^{(s)}} \right) \odot g(\boldsymbol{c}_{i,j}) + \boldsymbol{o}_{i,j} \odot \left( \vphantom{\frac{\partial \boldsymbol{c}_{i,j-1}}{\partial \boldsymbol{W}^{(s)}}} \left(1  - \tanh^2{(\boldsymbol{c}_{i,j})} \right)  \right. \\
        & \left. \cdot \left( \boldsymbol{s}_{i,j} \left( 1- \boldsymbol{s}_{i,j} \right) \left( \boldsymbol{x}_{i,j} + \boldsymbol{R}^{(s)}\frac{\partial \boldsymbol{h}_{i,j-1}}{\partial \boldsymbol{W}^{(s)}} \right) \odot \boldsymbol{z}_{i,j}  + \boldsymbol{f}_{i,j} \odot \frac{\partial \boldsymbol{c}_{i,j-1}}{\partial \boldsymbol{W}^{(s)}} \right) \right),
    \end{aligned}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
```

which looks like:
[image]

So I was wondering if there is a way to make this a bit more readable or somehow align them better. I had to split the second line into two because it didn't fit.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  You don't need so many `aligned` instances here.  One should do for the whole lot.  Or `split` should work.  Both are well documented in the `amsmath` user guide (`texdoc amsldoc`)  Also, spacing is better if the `&` is placed *before* the `=`, and use `\qquad` on a "second" line (one with no `=`).

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions! I will see if I can improve the equations this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need multiple nested `aligned` environments; a single `aligned[b]` environment suffices. I'd also get rid of the `\vphantom` construct and replace (almost) all instances of `\left` and `\right` with `\Bigl` and `\Bigr`, respectively. (A handful of `\left` and `\right` may be replaced with `\bigl` and `\bigr`.)

Next, since the term

```
\Bigl( \bm{o}_{ij} (1 - \bm{o}_{ij}) \bm{R}^{(0)}
    \frac{\partial\bm{h}_{ij-1}}{\partial\bm{W}^{(s)}} \Bigr) 
    \odot g(\bm{c}_{ij})
```

occurs three [3!] times in the main expression, I'd abbreviate it there (as `Z`, say) and define `Z` later on. Of course, you're free to come up with a term more distinctive that "`Z`".

Do consider loading the `bm` package (short for "bold math", I suppose) and replacing all 52 instances of `\boldsymbol` with `\bm`. Another comment: `\tanh` and `\tanh^2` do *not* take an argument that needs to be enclosed in curly braces.

[image]

---

A rather different comment/observation: It appears that you use the notational convention of **bold-facing** variable names. If that's the case, you're probably overdoing the **bold-facing** thing. Do try to get rid of all instances of the `\bm` wrappers and ask yourself if the readability of your work suffers. I'm pretty sure it will not. Ordinary instead of bold math-italics should suffice to signal to your readers that they're dealing with a variable:

[image]

---

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{amsmath,bm}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\label{eq:ML:LSTM:backpropagation_example}
\begin{aligned}[b]
\frac{\partial\bm{h}_{ij}}{\partial\bm{W}^{(s)}} 
&= \frac{\partial\bm{o}_{ij}}{\partial\bm{W}^{(s)}} 
   \odot g(\bm{c}_{ij}) +\bm{o}_{ij} 
   \odot \frac{\partial g(\bm{c}_{ij})}{\partial\bm{W}^{(s)}} \\
&= Z + \bm{o}_{ij} \odot \Bigl[ \bigl( 1 - \tanh^2(\bm{c}_{ij}) \bigr) 
   \frac{\partial\bm{c}_{ij}}{\partial\bm{W}^{(s)}} \Bigr]  \\
&= Z + \bm{o}_{ij} \odot \Bigl[ \bigl( 1 - \tanh^2(\bm{c}_{ij}) \bigr) 
   \Bigl( \frac{\partial\bm{s}_{ij}}{\partial\bm{W}^{(s)}} \odot \bm{z}_{ij} 
   + \bm{f}_{ij} \odot \frac{\partial\bm{c}_{ij-1}}{\partial\bm{W}^{(s)}} 
   \Bigr) \Bigr] \\
&= Z + \bm{o}_{ij} \odot \Bigl[ \bigl(1  - \tanh^2(\bm{c}_{ij}) \bigr) 
   \Bigl( \bm{s}_{ij} ( 1- \bm{s}_{ij} ) \\
&\qquad \times \Bigl( \bm{x}_{ij} + \bm{R}^{(s)}
   \frac{\partial\bm{h}_{ij-1}}{\partial\bm{W}^{(s)}} \Bigr) 
   \odot \bm{z}_{ij}
   + \bm{f}_{ij} \odot \frac{\partial\bm{c}_{ij-1}}{\partial\bm{W}^{(s)}} 
   \Bigr) \Bigr]
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
where
\[
Z = \Bigl( \bm{o}_{ij} (1 - \bm{o}_{ij}) \bm{R}^{(0)}
    \frac{\partial\bm{h}_{ij-1}}{\partial\bm{W}^{(s)}} \Bigr) 
    \odot g(\bm{c}_{ij})\,.
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, this looks very nice!
The bold-facing is to indicate vectors and matrices, as I have taken these from other resource material.